# How to Improve SQL readability and Performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following View:
So the question is,How to Improve SQL readability of this query?

```
    SELECT  t1.Id ,
            t1.HeaderRef ,
            t1.PartRef ,
            t1.SLRef ,
            t1.DL ,
            t1.DL2 ,
            t1.DL3 ,
            t1.DL4 ,
            t1.DL5 ,
            t1.DL6 ,
            t1.DL7 ,
            t1.ItemRef ,
            t1.CalItemRef ,
            t1.RowNum ,
            t1.UnitType ,
            t1.UnitTypeTitle ,
            t1.UnitRef ,
            t1.Ratio ,
            t1.Value ,
            t1.MasterValue ,
            t1.ItemDate ,
            t1.Descript ,
            t1.Year ,
            t1.BranchRef ,
            t1.StockRef ,
            t1.OpositStockRef ,
            t1.DocTypeRef ,
            t1.BaseDocTypeRef ,
            t1.Creator ,
            t1.Confirmer ,
            t1.Num ,
            t1.State ,
            t1.DocDate ,
            t1.FCRef ,
            t1.FCTitle ,
            t1.PartTitle ,
            t1.PartCode ,
            t1.SLCode ,
            t1.DL1Code ,
            t1.DL2Code ,
            t1.DL3Code ,
            t1.DL4Code ,
            t1.DL5Code ,
            t1.DL6Code ,
            t1.DL7Code ,
            t1.UnitTitle ,
            t1.PartUnitTitle , 
            ( ( AVG(t1.RealPrice) + SUM(t1.CorrectPrice) ) / t1.Value ) AS CorrectRate ,
            AVG(t1.RealPrice) + SUM(t1.CorrectPrice) AS CorrectPrice ,
            MAX(t1.CorrectAccDocHeaderRef) AS CorrectAccDocHeaderRef ,
            1 AS CorrectCreator ,
            1 AS CorrectConfirmer ,
            MAX(t1.CorrectCreateDate) AS CorrectCreateDate ,
            GETDATE() AS CorrectConfirmDate ,
            CorrectFCRate = ( SELECT    MAX(rr.FCRate)
                              FROM      Stc.StcDocRate AS rr
                              WHERE     rr.ItemRef = t1.Id
                                        AND rr.PriceType = '2'
                                        AND CreateDate = MAX(t1.CorrectCreateDate)
                            ) ,
            CorrectFCVal = ( SELECT MAX(rr.FCVal)
                             FROM   Stc.StcDocRate AS rr
                             WHERE  rr.ItemRef = t1.Id
                                    AND rr.PriceType = '2'
                                    AND CreateDate = MAX(t1.CorrectCreateDate)
                           ),
            CorrectDescript = ( SELECT  MAX(Descript)
                                FROM    Stc.StcDocRate AS rr
                                WHERE   rr.ItemRef = t1.Id
                                        AND rr.PriceType = '2'
                                        AND CreateDate = MAX(t1.CorrectCreateDate)
                              ) ,
            AVG(t1.RealPrice) / t1.Value AS RealRate ,
            AVG(t1.RealPrice) AS RealPrice ,
            MAX(t1.RealAccDocHeaderRef) AS RealAccDocHeaderRef ,
            1 AS RealCreator ,
            1 AS RealConfirmer ,
            GETDATE() AS RealCreateDate ,
            GETDATE() AS RealConfirmDate ,
            AVG(t1.RealFCRate) AS RealFCRate ,
            AVG(t1.RealFCVal) AS RealFCVal ,
            AVG(t1.CaledPrice) / t1.Value AS CaledRate ,
            AVG(t1.CaledPrice) AS CaledPrice ,
            MAX(t1.CaledAccDocHeaderRef) AS CaledAccDocHeaderRef ,
            1 AS CaledCreator ,
            1 AS CaledConfirmer ,
            GETDATE() AS CaledCreateDate ,
            GETDATE() AS CaledConfirmDate ,
            AVG(t1.CaledFCRate) AS CaledFCRate ,
            AVG(t1.CaledFCVal) AS CaledFCVal ,
            t1.ItemNum ,
            t1.BasePartCode ,
            t1.BasePartTitle ,
            t1.DlRefHeader ,
            t1.SLRefHeader,
            t1.ProductionValue ,
            t1.FormulaRef ,
            t1.StcDocReqRef
    FROM    ( SELECT    item.Id ,
                        item.HeaderRef ,
                        item.PartRef ,
                        item.SLRef ,
                        item.DL ,
                        item.DL2 ,
                        item.DL3 ,
                        item.DL4 ,
                        item.DL5 ,
                        item.DL6 ,
                        item.DL7 ,
                        item.ItemRef ,
                        item.CalItemRef ,
                        item.RowNum ,
                        item.UnitType ,
                        UnitTypeTitle = CASE item.UnitType
                                          WHEN '1' THEN N'اصلی'
                                          WHEN '2' THEN N'فرعی'
                                        END ,
                        item.UnitRef ,
                        item.Ratio ,
                        item.Value ,
                        item.MasterValue ,
                        item.ItemDate ,
                        item.Descript ,
                        item.StcDocReqRef ,
                        item.Year ,
                        item.BranchRef ,
                        item.StockRef ,
                        item.OpositStockRef ,
                        item.DocTypeRef ,
                        item.BaseDocTypeRef ,
                        item.Creator ,
                        item.Confirmer ,
                        item.Num ,
                        item.State ,
                        item.DocDate ,
                        item.FCRef ,
                        fc.Title AS FCTitle ,
                        item.ProductionValue ,
                        item.FormulaRef ,
                        p.Title AS PartTitle ,
                        p.Code AS PartCode ,
                        sl.SLCode AS SLCode ,
                        dl1.DLCode AS DL1Code ,
                        dl2.DLCode AS DL2Code ,
                        dl3.DLCode AS DL3Code ,
                        dl4.DLCode AS DL4Code ,
                        dl5.DLCode AS DL5Code ,
                        dl6.DLCode AS DL6Code ,
                        dl7.DLCode AS DL7Code ,
                        pu.Title AS UnitTitle ,
                        puslave.Title AS PartUnitTitle ,
                        CorrectRate.Rate AS CorrectRate ,
                        CorrectRate.Price AS CorrectPrice ,
                        CorrectRate.AccDocHeaderRef AS CorrectAccDocHeaderRef ,
                        CorrectRate.Creator AS CorrectCreator ,
                        CorrectRate.Confirmer AS CorrectConfirmer ,
                        CorrectRate.CreateDate AS CorrectCreateDate ,
                        CorrectRate.ConfirmDate AS CorrectConfirmDate ,
                        CorrectRate.FCRate AS CorrectFCRate ,
                        CorrectRate.FCVal AS CorrectFCVal ,
                        CorrectRate.Descript AS CorrectDescript ,
                        realRate.Rate RealRate ,
                        realRate.Price RealPrice ,
                        realRate.AccDocHeaderRef AS RealAccDocHeaderRef ,
                        realRate.Creator AS RealCreator ,
                        realRate.Confirmer AS RealConfirmer ,
                        realRate.CreateDate AS RealCreateDate ,
                        realRate.ConfirmDate AS RealConfirmDate ,
                        realRate.FCRate AS RealFCRate ,
                        realRate.FCVal AS RealFCVal ,
                        CaledRate.Rate AS CaledRate ,
                        CaledRate.Price AS CaledPrice ,
                        CaledRate.AccDocHeaderRef AS CaledAccDocHeaderRef ,
                        CaledRate.Creator AS CaledCreator ,
                        CaledRate.Confirmer AS CaledConfirmer ,
                        CaledRate.CreateDate AS CaledCreateDate ,
                        CaledRate.ConfirmDate AS CaledConfirmDate ,
                        CaledRate.FCRate AS CaledFCRate ,
                        CaledRate.FCVal AS CaledFCVal ,
                        ItemNum = CASE header.BaseDocTypeRef
                                    WHEN 2000 THEN refReqItem.Num
                                    WHEN 2002 THEN refOrderItem.Num
                                    WHEN 2003 THEN refFactItem.Num
                                    WHEN 2004 THEN refRetFactItem.Num
                                    WHEN 2010 THEN cmrPostItem.Num
                                    WHEN 2012 THEN cmrRet.Num
                                    WHEN 2016 THEN header.ProductionNum
                                    ELSE refItem.Num
                                  END ,
                        refPart.Code AS BasePartCode ,
                        refPart.Title AS BasePartTitle ,
                        header.DLRef AS DlRefHeader ,
                        header.SLRef AS SLRefHeader
              FROM      Stc.StcDocItem AS item
                        INNER JOIN Stc.Part AS p ON p.Id = item.PartRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.SL AS sl ON sl.Id = item.SLRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl1 ON dl1.Id = item.DL
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl2 ON dl2.Id = item.DL2
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl3 ON dl3.Id = item.DL3
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl4 ON dl4.Id = item.DL4
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl5 ON dl5.Id = item.DL5
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl6 ON dl6.Id = item.DL6
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.DL AS dl7 ON dl7.Id = item.DL7
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.FC AS fc ON fc.Id = item.FCRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.PartUnit AS pu ON pu.Id = item.UnitRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.PartUnit AS puslave ON puslave.Id = p.UnitRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.StcDocRate AS realRate ON realRate.ItemRef = item.Id
                                                              AND realRate.PriceType = '1'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.StcDocRate AS CorrectRate ON CorrectRate.ItemRef = item.Id
                                                              AND CorrectRate.PriceType = '2'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.StcDocRate AS CaledRate ON CaledRate.ItemRef = item.Id
                                                              AND CaledRate.PriceType = '3'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.StcDocItem AS refItem ON refItem.Id = item.ItemRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.Part AS refPart ON refItem.PartRef = refPart.Id
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.StcDocReqItem AS refReqItem ON refReqItem.Id = item.ItemRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sle.SleDocOrderItem AS refOrderItem ON refOrderItem.Id = item.ItemRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sle.SleDocFactItem AS refFactItem ON refFactItem.Id = item.ItemRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sle.SleDocRetFactItem AS refRetFactItem ON refRetFactItem.Id = item.ItemRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN CMR.CMRIntSheetPostItem AS cmrPostItem ON cmrPostItem.Id = item.ItemRef
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN CMR.CMRIntReturnPartNonConformingItem
                        AS cmrRet ON cmrRet.Id = item.ItemRef 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Stc.StcDocHeader AS header ON header.Id = item.HeaderRef
            ) AS t1
```

Readability of this query is pretty bad. In particular, i had problem to understand.

I would like some feedback how to improve performance and Readability for this case?

Comment: Break the query into smaller pieces by creating one or more CTEs.  And in doing so, besides making things more digestable, you might even get a performance gain.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Can you help me to do this ?

Comment: Performance and readability often don't go together. For performance, use the query plan (CTRL-L) to understand where the performance issue is and add indexes. In this query, which tables have the most records? Readability is a different thing. It's as readable as it can be. Its a complicated query and that's all there is to it unfortunately.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen CTE's are rarely a performance booster, if ever, because it's just a disposable view.

Comment: Useful indentation, informative aliases, tidy joins, reasonable column names, ... . And a nice hat. I've seen _much_ worse. I'll toss out one personal preference that applies to pretty much any language: Any statement that is continued on the next line should have something dangling. For example, if you happen to see `WHERE rr.ItemRef = t1.Id` at the bottom of your scrolling window will you scroll down to see `AND rr.PriceType = '2'` on the next line? If the bottom line was `WHERE rr.ItemRef = t1.Id AND` then you would _know_ that there is more to come.

Answer (score 1):

**1. readability**

- if you have to get one output select with all this columns, your query is well formed enough
- if you can decompose your qry, so split it into smaller logical (or semantically connected) blocks
- use views for pivoted output - for example instead of 8x Acc.SL left join create view with pivoted data
- use functions or views to remove case statement or subqueries
- separate agregations and other data (it seems in your qry is missing group by statement)

**2. performance**

- get query plan
- rewrite your query to use existing indexes or add missing indexes
- force joins order if it's necessary